# Is it possible to call server side methods directly on meteor shell?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Collection 'Entries' set up and a meteor server side method defined:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Entries = new Mongo.Collection('entries');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // This code only runs on the server
    Meteor.publish('entries', function entriesPublication() {
        return Entries.find({$or: [
        { id_user: this.userId },
      ],});
    });
}

Meteor.methods({
'entries.setPosition'(entryId, position) {
        check(entryId, String);
        check(position, Number);

        Entries.update(entryId, { $set: { position: position } });
});
```

Is it possible to somehow call entries.setPosition() in meteor or mongo shell with different parameters and see the results? I would like to avoid re-writing or pasting (which messes the formatting) the whole mongo query directly on the console. How could I see the affected rows after executing a function?

Comment: Why not just use the node debugger? https://coderwall.com/p/eqecca/server-debugging-with-meteor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would do that just like calling from client side.